# java access variable from another class

Tags: java, inheritance, package, subclass, extends

I am having trouble accessing a String from another class and I have no idea  how much more simpler I can make it. For example I have a class called "Person" and I have a String name. I set the "name" for name via a constructor and also directly. And I have another class called Loan which I am not trying to access anything yet. My final class is called "App" and that's where everything is done.

Btw - Person is my superclass, and Loan extends Person, and App extends Loan and they are all within the same Package.

Now in my App class I tried accessing the String "name" for the ONLY person object I made. And again I assigned the name via a constructor and directly but somehow that is not working. And originally I had my name set is protected because how I understand it:
protected = access methods/variables in same class, same package, or subclass
And even AFTER i made my String public it is STILL not working. I am totally lost....

when I type

```
  System.out.println(omid.name);
```

it says that it can't be resolved to a variable and I need to make a local one.

Thank you!

Here is my code for Person:

```
package Programs;

public class Person {
    public String name;
    protected int age;
    protected int id;
    protected String status;
    protected int alienNumber;
    protected int socialSecurityNumber;

    Person()
    {

    }

    Person(String name, int age, int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
    }



    public void setid(int id)
    {
        if(id >= 100000)
        {
            this.socialSecurityNumber = id;
            System.out.println("You are now a citizen " + name);
            System.out.println("Social Security Number: " + socialSecurityNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry " + name + " you do not meet the qualitifactions for citizenship");
            alienNumber = id;
            System.out.println("You alien number is: " + alienNumber);

        }
    }



    public String toString()
    {
        if(id >=99000 )
        {
            status = "citizen";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "immigrant";
        }

        return "Name: " + name + 
                "Age: " + age + 
                "Id: " + id +
                "Status " + status;
        }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Person omid = new Person("omid nassir", 28, 120000);
    omid.name = "omid";
}




}
```

Code for Loan

```
package Programs;

import Programs.Person;


public class Loan extends Person{


    public static final int LOANAMOUNT1 = 250000;
    public static final int LOANAMOUNT2 = 500000;
    public static final int LOANAMOUNT3 = 750000;
    public static final int LOANAMOUNT4 = 1000000;
    public int income;
    public int loanRequested;


    Loan(int income, int socialSecurityNumber, int loanRequested)
    {
        this.income = income;
        this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
        this.loanRequested = loanRequested;
    }


    public void applyForLoan(String name, int socialSecurityNumber, int income, int loanAmount)
    {
     int obtainable = LOANAMOUNT1 / 4;
        if(socialSecurityNumber >= 99999)
        {
            if(income > obtainable)
            {
                obtainable = loanAmount;
                System.out.println("Congradulations " + name + " you are eligible for loan amount of " + loanAmount);
            }
        }
        else if(socialSecurityNumber <=99999)
        {
            obtainable = LOANAMOUNT1;
            System.out.println("Sorry " + name + " in order to qualify for " + loanAmount + " you need to be"
                    + " a citizen and have a minimum income of " + obtainable);
            System.out.println("Loan amount granted: " + LOANAMOUNT1);
        }
    }


}
```

Code for App

```
package Programs;

public class App extends Person {

        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(omid.name);
    }


}
```

Comment: You have 2 `main(String[] args)` methods (in App and Person). I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you need only 1

Comment: "App" is extending "Person" so the string "name" should be inherited. So you can access it like you access local variables. `System.out.println(name);` Except if "omid" is another "Person". But in your case you have only 1 person object so it should work with just `name`instead of `omid.name`

Comment: When App class extends a Person, it does not mean in the App.main() you will have things you created in Person.main()

Comment: @AlexNevidomsky - Okay, that's what my main issue was thanks. But just one question. If I am extending a class, what do i inherit? Thanks.

Comment: Very roughly speaking you get methods and fields that are not private. But it's a long topic with many details, and you better study it separately. The trick here is that you "lose" that inheritance when creating things with the same name in the new class. Then you have to call the "old version" explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `omid` within the `main` method in `App`. You defined `omid` within `main` of `Person`, but this variable cannot be accessed, since this is an entirely different scope. You might want to read up on `static` and its semantics.

Comment: I know what static does, I am trying to create a program for practice where I can create multiple people and based on their status if they are eligible for a loan or not. So if I made the String name static it would change for every instance. I am still new to Java so I might be wrong. but i will read up on static again. Thanks.

Comment: Making it static implies it is shared by all objects of that class (type). Changing it's value implies that it will be changed for all instances of that class.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want it to be shared by ALL instances. I wanted to make like a dozen different objects of type Person, all with their own names, incomes, etc...

Comment: Then you're defining your person object at the wrong place. Defining it within your "main" method in the "Person" class implies the main method will be called for each Person object you are making. So everytime you make a new Person object you are making "omid" again and again. You want to define Person objects outside the Person class itself.  For example in the "App" class. And like I said, if you want to print the name of the Person itself, you can use `name` *within the class itself*, as it is a local variable.

Comment: @rissandimo if you don't see what is wrong with your `main` method within `App`, you definitively need to read up on statics and visibility/lifetime of variables.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will do. Thanks for everyone help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `static void main()` methods.  Only the one in `App` is run.  I see that `App extends Person`; I don't think that is what you want.  Static methods cannot be overridden; it is not going to automagically call your main method in `Person`.  The only statement that is executed in your program is

```
System.out.println(omid.name);
```